# Run only tests through gradle task that have two specific groups

Tags: java, testing, gradle, testng

So, I have a class with tests like this:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


@Test
public class TestClass {

    @Test(groups = {"smoke", "a", "b"})
    public void testOne() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2, 2);
    }

    @Test(groups = {"integration", "a", "b"})
    public void testTwo() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test(groups = {"smoke", "b"})
    public void testThree() {
        Assert.assertEquals("str", "str");
    }
}
```

and the gradle task:

```
task smokeB {
    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups 'smoke', 'b'
    }
}
```

But this works like `or` statement and run tests that have `smoke` or `b` groups.

Is it possible to run only tests that have both groups?
So, something like: `includeGroups 'smoke' && 'b'`